# Натяжка слайдера wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Проблема состоит в ошибке цикла foreach (invalid argument supplied for foreach()). Собственно, код:

```
<?php 
$sliders_main = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'main_slider_list', true );
?>
<main>
    <div class="main-slider">
        <div class="slide"></div>
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

    <?php 
    if (is_array($values) || is_object($values))
        {           
        foreach ($sliders_main as $slider) :

    ?> 
    <div class="item" data-src="<?php echo $slider[main_slider_list_upload] ; ?>">
        <div class="item-text center">
            <p><span>SIMPLE</span> - lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
            <span><a href="#">Read more</a></span>
            <p><?php echo $slider[main_slider_list_header] ; ?></p>
        </div>
    </div> 
            <?php
                endforeach;
            }
            ?> 
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Как видно, присутствует проверка на наличие массива, но это лишь помогает убрать ошибку из консоли. Контент не выводится все равно. Вот, собственно, массив:

```
array(
    'id'          => 'main_slider_list',
    'label'       => 'Slider',
    'desc'        => '',
    'std'         => '',
    'type'        => 'list-item',
    'condition'   => 'main_slider_show:is(on)',
    'settings'    => array( 
      array(
        'id'          => 'main_slider_list_text',
        'label'       => 'Write a text',
        'desc'        => '',
        'type'        => 'text',
      ),
      array(
        'id'          => 'main_slider_list_upload',
        'label'       => 'Download the slide',
        'desc'        => '',
        'type'        => 'upload',
      ),
    )
  ),
```

В чем может крыться проблема? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что за $values в проверяете? Переменная не существует в вашем воде, if не выполняется.

Comment: А ошибка в foreach оттого, что $sliders_main не массив. А объект, например.

Comment: Уже убрал проверку, ошибка пропала (хотя раньше была). Но контент все равно не отображается, хотя слайды в админке залиты и сам блок отображается на странице

Comment: И вот это никогда не сработает $slider[main_slider_list_header]

Comment: Так $sliders_main переменная , которая принимает массив

Comment: Вы отлаживайтесь - распечатывайте переменные через var_dump или плагин phpConsole, смотрите, что у вас с кодом. Вопрос не для SO.

Comment: И почему $slider[main_slider_list_header] не сработает?

Comment: потому что внутри квадратных скобок должен быть ключ массива в виде СТРОКИ с 'aaaaa' или "aaaaa" или переменная $ffff. А то что вы написали - ошибка синтаксиса

Comment: Проголосовал за закрытие вопроса, потому что тут ошибка на ошибке.

Comment: Ладно, буду дальше разбираться. Спасибо.